# change scss element's attribute using typescript

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, sass

In SCSS, how can I change an element's attribute, for example:

```
a1{
   a2{
      img{
          top: 0;
}}}
```

how do I change the value - 0 to 10 with typescript if the .scss file is inside the same folder as the .ts file.

Comment: During runtime, it's not possible to change a file content (in fact you don't have that original file anymore after your app is compiled). The best you can do is set the attribute for the element. Is it angular, react or pure javascript?

Comment: @julianobrasil it would be angular for my case

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, supposing you have something like the HTML bellow, you can change the style inline:

```html
<img [ngStyle]="_style" ...>
```

```js
get _style(): {[key: string]: string} {
  // you can define any logic to calculate the top property:

  if(condition_1) {
    return {top: 0};
  } else {
    return {top: 10};
  }
}
```

You can get more info on [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngstyle).